# How to send and retrieve a specific Content-Type with AWS ApiGateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, content-type

I'm newbie in AWS, and work on a already created project. 
I need to create a route which send a specific Content-Type, but when I check the lambda, the retrieved Content-Type is not the one as expected.

What I do:
[image]

and what I recover:

```
content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0
```

Is there a good way to use a specific content-type and retrieve it?
Thank for your help

**Edit1**
I also follow this [tuto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) but without any success